# WebSphere Liberty Profile custom log location using bootstrap.properties

Tags: logging, websphere-liberty

I have added the bootstrap.properties with the following entry

```
 com.ibm.ws.logging.log.directory=/opt/ibm/wlp/servers/CustomServer/customlogdirectory/
```

As per the documentation, it says all the logs will be generated in the above mentioned directory. "messages.log's" are getting generated and stored within the directory as mentioned in the bootstrap.properties. But I see "console.log" is getting updated under the location **/opt/ibm/wlp/servers/CustomServer/logs**

Can someone guide me on how to redirect all the logs into the one mentioned in the bootstrap.properties file ?

Answer (score 4):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

> This file is created only if the server start command is used, and its
>   location c**an be altered only by using the LOG_DIR environment variable**